# Why does the program compile and run so slowly unlike ususal?

Tags: compilation, console

When I compile and run a small program such as "printf("hello world")!", My all IDEs or comand line to run this program is so slowly. I must wait a few seconds,then the console will print characters or display my input characters.How to solve this problem.

[image]

An example is shown above,the screen does not show the characters I typed until about 10 sec.

It doesn't take long to compile directly but it takes a long time to compile and run.
I tried such as codeblocks20.03, visual studio 2022, visual studio code with code runner and command line by using g++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this bug. The reason is that I installed Cheat Engine a few days ago. It brought a virus defender Ravantivirus, uninstall it could solve the problem.